Disintegration effect on several parts of the mesh using geo nodes
I have created Geo nodes with a simulation for a disintegration effect (I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlVuIh3td9g ).
Currently, there is a boolean that determines where the points should come and "dissolve," but is it possible to have several different booleans (or a smarter method) so that the Disintegration effect occurs in several different places simultaneously?
Here is the file:



Short version, probably yes. I’d have to watch the whole tutorial, but somewhere there’s a Boolean for the one sphere object. You just need to distribute points along the surface of the mesh, instance spheres at those points, and use them for the Boolean instead.
